# How to make scrollbar always visible

Tags: css

I want to make the scrollbar always visible. The problem is that I see it in chrome and safari, but not on Iphone and in mozilla.

I have next code

```
<div class="scrollbar">
   Scrollable content
</div>
```

and the css code is as follows:

```
/* Scroll thumb styles */
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
}
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

On Android devices or in Chrome and Safari on desktop I see something as follows:

[image]

But on Iphone safari I do not see it:

[image]

I see it when I start to scroll and it has default styling.

Any idea?

Comment: [`overflow: visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#visible)

Comment: According to this post, custom scrollbars are no longer supported in iOS :S https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670065

Comment: @DiegoN. this seems to be confirmed by https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar so I guess one is reduced to implementing a home-grown scrollbar with JS. Not great.

Answer (score 0):

Change width: 100% to width: 7px will work

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 2px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to make both scrollbars always visible use overflow: scroll, make only x-axis scrollbar visible use overflow-x and overflow-y for y-axis. use overflow: auto when you want to display the scrollbar when there is content larger then the container

Comment: If you have code suggestions, please try to make use of the code formatting to make it more clear to the TS